# Mobile regexp user agent

Tags: php, regex, mobile

i have to check in my script for user agent for mobile.

i have

```
if(preg_match('/lg|iphone|blackberry|opera/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) { ... }
```

i found out the `lg` one needs to be the first part of the string

eg:

```
lg-9000 ...
lg1000 ...
lg 2000 ...
lge4300 ...
```

basically i want to know if it's possible to find if the string (from my regexp) can be found in the user agent starting from the beginning, not somewhere in the string.

*i would like not to change my regex string*

thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the meta character `^` to denote start of string. You can read more about it [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html). The following pattern will only match `lg` if it's in the start of the string:

```
^lg|iphone|blackberry|opera/
```

You can see a simple example it in action here: http://regexr.com?2vjec

Answer (score -2):

I'm using this library to detect OS and browser info
http://chrisschuld.com/projects/browser-php-detecting-a-users-browser-from-php/

Comment: does not work, i have `Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows Phone OS 7.0; Trident/3.1; IEMobile/7.0) LG;LG-E900
` and it does not say it's a mobile phone AND i say my os is **unknow**. also. it say **iPhone 4** and my user agent is `Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_0 like Mac OS X; en-us)`