# Redirecting based on mobile using php

Tags: php, mobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP mobile browser detection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817155/php-mobile-browser-detection)

How can I use PHP to display different sites based on whether the user is on a mobile or desktop device?

Comment: Similar question, look at this answer for PHP link : http://stackoverflow.com/a/1005162/1093649 (better be using apache rules if you can)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660555/mobile-regexp-user-agent

Comment: Frndz thanks a lot.i had got the answer...

Answer (score 0):

There is a [mobile detection plugin](http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/) for PHP that would allow you to specify how the user views the page. If you didn't want to do pure CSS changes, you could forward them on to a subdomain (m.mysite.com) to a virtual path (mysite.com/mobile) using this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need basic knowledge on implementation such work. Ok you have to do two things.

1. First you have to detect whether the request came from a mobile device or from a computer.
2. For visual aspects you can redirect user to your mobile page or you can display same page as a mobile friendly page using relevant HTML and CSS rules.

To detect whether the request came from a mobile device. You can use some plugin or a class already developed. It will make your work easier.

I have used following class for one of my project and it works well.

http://chrisschuld.com/projects/browser-php-detecting-a-users-browser-from-php/

Cheers!