# Can I target specific browsers/devices with the Manifest or Appcache file or just exclude the appcache from Desktop browsers?

Tags: php, android, ios, html, html5-appcache

Essentially I would like to be able to use an appcache file on my site but only for mobile devices, to enable those devices to view the website/webapp I am developing offline, however desktops/laptops often have access to the internet and I would rather these view the site as is, with no manifest/caching etc..

I am aware user agent sniffing is at best unreliable although can provide some good results, if this could be avoided it would be best.

The site/webapp I am developing is built in HTML/CSS/JS/PHP and uses responsive layouts to serve the same pages of the site to each device with customised views/layouts depending on the devices width (using css media queries).

Thanks for any help in advance, all my searches for this specifically have proved unfruitful :(

**Update**

After Robertc's comments below I would like to clarify that it is Desktop Browsers (ie the very same browsers that are used on laptops) that I would like to exclude any caching from via appcache/manifest file... This is a requirement from client and also from me as programmatically it seems easier to target desktops and laptops together as they are using same software/OS...

More specifically my webapp needs to support caching via appcache/manifest on iOS, Android & Blackberry (although it would be nice to have all tablets/smartphones) so maybe the question is how to find one of these devices and include the appcache reference, however this looks like it is leading down the path of user agent sniffing which I was hoping to avoid...

Comment: I didn't specifically say a laptop is not a mobile device although it could look I'm implying it, however when doing user agent sniffing laptops don't normally get picked up as mobile because they share the same OS' & Browsers etc with their desktop counterparts...


Either way the real need is to seperate laptop/desktop from all other mobile devices, the following browers I would like caching in the manifest/appcache way disabled (desktop versions), however the requirement is all desktop browers to behave without caching: Chrome, IE, Firefox, Safari

Comment: Thanks @robertc but as I said in my questions I know this is not a good way, however it's the only one I can think of, any suggestions welcome.....

Comment: In regards to the connectivity, this is not correct, I do not want people on laptops to cache the site if they are frequently disconnected from the internet and people on laptops that are always connected to internet to not cache the site, all laptops should not cache the the site regardless of connectivity, your suggestion in other circumstances would be perfect but I fear technology is not developed enough to allow for this kind of detection reliably.

Comment: Robertc I never said laptops are always connected to the internet, it also has no relevance to my needs or the solution that will be implemented, FYI in this scenario, the laptops being used within the business are connected to the internet all day when people get in to the office.... let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20698/discussion-between-acslater-and-robertc)

Comment: *****Just to note, it appears a user called "robertc" was trolling and after being very annoying deleted all his comments*****

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the browser does check the Appcache.manifast before everything else happens, you have to do an additional serverside detection. You cannot load the appcache.manifest by javascript.

Make a Serverside detection on the Useragent and deliver the HTML with manifest if you get a request from iphone, ipad, android etc. and without manifest in the other cases.

User Agent checking is the best approach. You deliver your site for people who doesn't fake there User Agent.

User agent test with php for mobile devices (just add your devices you need):

- [Mobile regexp user agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660555/mobile-regexp-user-agent)
- http://chrisschuld.com/projects/browser-php-detecting-a-users-browser-from-php/

Comment: Thanks Sam, after testing and trying things out the past few days this does indeed look like the only way forward :(  I hate any testing on the user agent because it requires too much work to maintain and it's near impossible to future proof... Leaving the question open a bit longer but I think this is the correct answer

Comment: I guess you should not think about maintenance it to much.
Testing on: iPhone, iPad, Android, Blackberry, WindowsPhone sould be enogh. You can enhance it as soon you need to support appcache for more devices. (Not every mobile browser support appcache...)

Comment: I know what you mean but once I hand the project over I want it to be as stable and working for as long as possible, any new handsets that get released will be most likely to support appcache and eventually will improve on those, I would like the the app to support those handsets but there is no 100% way of enabling this... I am currently using regex script to check devices however haven't come across those links, will take a look further, thanks!